# Problema Xaamp al arrancar Servidor Mysql

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, windows10, mysqldb

Tengo Windows10 con Xaamp que ha estado funcionado 2 meses, hoy al abrir el PC e intentar encender el servidor me da un error, y si miro el log de mysql me dice lo siguiente.

```
 2020-04-20 17:42:41 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
    2020-04-20 17:42:41 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
    2020-04-20 17:42:41 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
    2020-04-20 17:42:41 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
    2020-04-20 17:42:41 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
    2020-04-20 17:42:41 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
    2020-04-20 17:42:41 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
    2020-04-20 17:42:41 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
    2020-04-20 17:42:41 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
    2020-04-20 17:42:41 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
    2020-04-20 17:42:41 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
    2020-04-20 17:42:41 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
    2020-04-20 17:42:41 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.11 started; log sequence number 744521349; transaction id 555207
    2020-04-20 17:42:41 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
    2020-04-20 17:42:41 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
    2020-04-20 17:42:41 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

Se os ocurre como puedo hacer para recuperar las bases de datos?
Gracias

Archivo de log entero

```
> InnoDB: using atomic writes.
2020-04-20 18:14:10 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2020-04-20 18:14:10 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2020-04-20 18:14:10 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2020-04-20 18:14:10 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2020-04-20 18:14:10 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2020-04-20 18:14:10 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2020-04-20 18:14:10 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2020-04-20 18:14:10 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery from checkpoint LSN=300288
2020-04-20 18:14:10 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2020-04-20 18:14:10 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2020-04-20 18:14:10 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2020-04-20 18:14:10 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2020-04-20 18:14:10 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2020-04-20 18:14:10 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2020-04-20 18:14:10 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.11 started; log sequence number 300297; transaction id 171
2020-04-20 18:14:10 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2020-04-20 18:14:10 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2020-04-20 18:14:10 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 200420 18:14:10
2020-04-20 18:14:10 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
InnoDB: using atomic writes.
2020-04-20 18:16:41 0 [Note] InnoDB: The first innodb_system data file 'ibdata1' did not exist. A new tablespace will be created!
2020-04-20 18:16:41 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2020-04-20 18:16:41 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2020-04-20 18:16:41 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2020-04-20 18:16:41 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2020-04-20 18:16:41 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2020-04-20 18:16:41 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2020-04-20 18:16:41 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2020-04-20 18:16:41 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibdata1' size to 10 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2020-04-20 18:16:41 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibdata1' size is now 10 MB.
2020-04-20 18:16:41 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting log file C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_logfile101 size to 5242880 bytes
2020-04-20 18:16:41 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting log file C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_logfile1 size to 5242880 bytes
2020-04-20 18:16:41 0 [Note] InnoDB: Renaming log file C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_logfile101 to C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_logfile0
2020-04-20 18:16:41 0 [Note] InnoDB: New log files created, LSN=11452
2020-04-20 18:16:41 0 [Note] InnoDB: Doublewrite buffer not found: creating new
2020-04-20 18:16:41 0 [Note] InnoDB: Doublewrite buffer created
2020-04-20 18:16:41 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2020-04-20 18:16:41 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating foreign key constraint system tables.
2020-04-20 18:16:41 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating tablespace and datafile system tables.
2020-04-20 18:16:41 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating sys_virtual system tables.
2020-04-20 18:16:41 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2020-04-20 18:16:41 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2020-04-20 18:16:41 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2020-04-20 18:16:41 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2020-04-20 18:16:41 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.11 started; log sequence number 0; transaction id 7
2020-04-20 18:16:41 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2020-04-20 18:16:41 0 [Note] Zerofilling moved table:  '.\mysql\plugin'
2020-04-20 18:16:41 0 [Note] Zerofilling moved table:  '.\mysql\servers'
2020-04-20 18:16:41 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
InnoDB: using atomic writes.
2020-04-20 18:18:11 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2020-04-20 18:18:11 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2020-04-20 18:18:11 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2020-04-20 18:18:11 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2020-04-20 18:18:11 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2020-04-20 18:18:11 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2020-04-20 18:18:11 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2020-04-20 18:18:11 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery from checkpoint LSN=47055
2020-04-20 18:18:12 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2020-04-20 18:18:12 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2020-04-20 18:18:12 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2020-04-20 18:18:12 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2020-04-20 18:18:12 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2020-04-20 18:18:12 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2020-04-20 18:18:12 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.11 started; log sequence number 47064; transaction id 9
2020-04-20 18:18:12 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2020-04-20 18:18:12 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2020-04-20 18:18:12 0 [Note] InnoDB: Cannot open 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool' for reading: No such file or directory
2020-04-20 18:18:12 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
InnoDB: using atomic writes.
2020-04-20 18:23:42 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2020-04-20 18:23:42 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2020-04-20 18:23:42 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2020-04-20 18:23:42 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2020-04-20 18:23:42 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2020-04-20 18:23:42 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2020-04-20 18:23:42 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2020-04-20 18:23:42 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery from checkpoint LSN=47073
2020-04-20 18:23:42 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2020-04-20 18:23:42 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2020-04-20 18:23:42 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2020-04-20 18:23:42 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2020-04-20 18:23:42 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2020-04-20 18:23:42 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2020-04-20 18:23:42 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.11 started; log sequence number 47082; transaction id 9
2020-04-20 18:23:42 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2020-04-20 18:23:42 0 [Note] InnoDB: Cannot open 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool' for reading: No such file or directory
2020-04-20 18:23:42 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2020-04-20 18:23:42 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
InnoDB: using atomic writes.
2020-04-20 18:25:56 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2020-04-20 18:25:56 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2020-04-20 18:25:56 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2020-04-20 18:25:56 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2020-04-20 18:25:56 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2020-04-20 18:25:56 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2020-04-20 18:25:56 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2020-04-20 18:25:56 0 [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence number 0 in the system tablespace does not match the log sequence number 47116 in the ib_logfiles!
2020-04-20 18:25:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2020-04-20 18:25:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2020-04-20 18:25:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2020-04-20 18:25:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2020-04-20 18:25:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2020-04-20 18:25:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2020-04-20 18:25:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.11 started; log sequence number 47116; transaction id 9
2020-04-20 18:25:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2020-04-20 18:25:57 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2020-04-20 18:25:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Cannot open 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool' for reading: No such file or directory
2020-04-20 18:25:57 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

Comment: ¿Qué error te da? EN el log no hay nada.

Comment: Dices `intentar encender el servidor me da un error`. ¿Qué error da? El log muestra que la BD arranca normalmente, el buffer file no está (y no sabemos si manipulaste la estructura de archivos manualmente)